# php- Editing profile page of a user

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i would like to allow the user to  update the details of himself (profile page)
my page works fine but when i click the update button the page just refreshes and the details stay unchange here is my code.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



    if( isset($_POST['username']) )
    {
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $id  = $_POST['user_id'];
        $sql  = "UPDATE users SET user_name='$username' user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
        $res    = mysql_query($sql) 
                                    or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
    }
            if( isset($_POST['useremail']) )
    {
        $useremail= $_POST['useremail'];
        $id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $sql  = "UPDATE users SET user_email='$useremail' WHEREuser_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
        $res = mysql_query($sql) 
                                    or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
    }

        if( isset($_POST['userabout']) )
    {
        $userabout= $_POST['userabout'];
        $id  = $_POST['user_id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_about='$userabout' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user'];
        $res = mysql_query($sql) 
                                    or die("Could not update".mysql_affected_rows());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
    }

error_reporting(-1);
?>






<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo $userRow['user_email']; ?>s Profile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">

    <input type="button"/>

        <div class="menubar">
            <div class="menu">
                             <ul id="menubar">
                <li><?php echo $userRow['user_email']; ?><a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            <div class="menu1">
            <ul id="menubar">
                <li><a class="upload" href="index1.php">Upload</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

</div>







    <div class="main">
<form action="profile.php" method="POST">
<div>
<label for="uname"><a>User Name:</a></label>
<input type="text" name="username"  value="<?php echo $userRow['user_name'];?>"/>
</div>

<div>
<label for="email"><a>Email:</a></label>
<input type="text" name="useremail"  value="<?php  echo $userRow['user_email'];?>"/>
</div>
<div>
<label for="about"><a>About me:</a></label>
<textarea name="userabout" rows="10" cols="30"><?php echo $userRow['user_about'];?></textarea>
</div>

<input type="submit"  value="Update">
<div>
</div>

</form>







 </div>



     <div id="mainv">
<table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">your uploads...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>File Name</td>
    <td>File Type</td>
    <td>File Size(KB)</td>
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>

<video width="700" height="500" controls="autoplay">
  <source src="mmm.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
</source>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>

        <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"target="frame_a">view file</a></td>
</a>        
</tr>
        <?php
 }
?>
   </table>


  </div>
  <div class="mid">
  <div class="main2"><div class="pop"><div class="pop1"><h2>More Popular videos<h2></div><div class="pop2"></div></div></div>
  <div class="com"><div class="comm"><div class="comm1"><h2>Best comments of the week<h2></div><div class="comm2"></div></div></div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

i know this is old php  but i started my project with it half way through the project i realized that there are newer version.

Could u help me out here thanks.

****I EDITED THE CODE AND I GOT THE FOLLWING ERROR**** 
Could not updateYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_id=36' at line 1

Comment: if you want to truly want to know if your UPDATE worked, use `mysql_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php as you might be getting a false positive here. Yet, why the multiples of `include_once 'dbconfig.php';`?

Comment: and when you refresh the page(using the browser refresh button) do you see your updates? If yes, then fetch the `$userRow`  after you "UPDATE" the record

Comment: and where's this coming from? `$_GET['edit']` I see no reference to it, same thing for `$_POST['user_id']`. check for errors then come back to us. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I cant see the updates after i hit the button the page refreshes but the details stay unchanged

Comment: I edited the code I got rid of the $_GET['edit'] and i got the following error     Could not updateYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_id=36' at line 1. anny thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bind `$id` to `$_POST['user_id']` which the form in your html doesn't even post? Apparently you have the users ID in the `$_SESSION['user']` variable.

Also, your SQL statements are broken.

Your code could look something like this:

```
if( isset($_POST['username']) )
{
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $id  = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sql  = "UPDATE users SET user_name='$username' WHERE user_id=$id";
    $res    = mysql_query($sql) 
                                or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
}

if( isset($_POST['useremail']) )
{
    $useremail= $_POST['useremail'];
    $id  = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sql  = "UPDATE users SET user_email='$useremail' WHERE user_id=$id";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) 
                                or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
}

if( isset($_POST['userabout']) )
{
    $userabout= $_POST['userabout'];
    $id  = $_SESSION['user'];
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_about='$userabout' WHERE user_id=$id";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) 
                                or die("Could not update".mysql_affected_rows());
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=profile.php'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks man It works fine know .

Comment: Great, though you really should use prepared statements as your current code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

1) There is a `WHERE` missing in your first statement and a space in the second.

2) You have an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. The values comes from user input and are unsanitized.

The correct code would be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "' WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_email='" . mysql_real_escape_string($useremail) . "' WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user'];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET user_about='" . mysql_real_escape_string($userabout) . "' WHERE user_id=" . $_SESSION['user'];
```

To prevent SQL injection, I used `mysql_real_escape_string` here to keep the rest of your code the same, but you should definitely look into the subject of "prepared statements".